# Send different data to same client with nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

i have a problem with my NodeJS application.
I want to send differents data on one client. I have realtime data from a Java program, and i have data from a database. That's work, i see two data but i want to send realtime data on a graphic and database data in a table. I don't know how to distinguish them. I use socket.io and mysql.

**Server**

```js
socket.on('connection', function(client){
    console.log('Le client s\'est connecté au serveur');
    socketnavigateur = client; //socketnavigateur is a global variable for realtime data.
    
    var selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Depassement";
        conn.query(selectQuery, function select(error, rows, fields){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
                conn.end();
                return;
            }
   
            if(rows.length > 0){
                var Result = rows[0];
                client.send('id: '  + Result['Id_depassement']);
                client.send('Date : ' +  Result['Date_Dep']);
                client.send('Heure : '+ Result['Heure_Dep']);
                client.send('Puissance: ' + Result['P_reactive']);
            } else{
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
   
   
    //Message listener
    client.on('message', function(event){
        console.log('Réception du message du client =',event);
    });
   
    client.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log('Le client s\'est déconnecté !');
    });
});
```

**Client**

```js
var socket = io.connect();

        // connection listener
        socket.on('connect',function() {
            log('<span style="color:green;">Le serveur s\'est connecte au client !</span>');

        });
        // message listener
        socket.on('message',function(data) {
            log(data);
            console.log(data);
            drawGraph(data);
        });

        socket.on('disconnect',function() {
            log('<span style="color:red;">Le client s\'est déconnecte !</span>');
        });

        // function to display on client
        function log(message) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            li.innerHTML = message;
            document.getElementById('message-list').appendChild(li);
            document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = message;
}
```

Thanks for your help and sorry if my english is bad :p

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to a `socket.io` server, you include some payload, like so:

*client.js*

```
 const socketOptions = {
        query: {
            user_id: someUniqueId,
            client_type: 'peasant'
        }
    }

socketIO.connect('socket-domain', socketOptions)
```

And then on the server, you need to capture this data, you can also capture a unique client ID that you use to send data to:

*server.js*

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    const dataFromUser = socket.handshake.query // this is the data
    // so you may access, for example dataFromUser.user_id

    // this is a unique ID generated by socket.io
    const clientId = socket.id

    // You can use this id to send data to specific users e.g:
    io.to(clientId).emit('message', 'You have 1 new message')
})
```

I'll leave it up to you how you store the IDs and retrieve them, you may use `redis` or `memcached`

Comment: I type socketOptions on the client ? and what is 'socket-domain' ?

Comment: yes, updated. Above is for client, below is server. 'socket-domain' is the URL you want to connect for example, `http://localhost:5012` or `http://my-website.com/socket`. I think you can leave it empty and just use `socketIO.connect(socketOptions)`

Comment: Ok thanks, i will try and i will say to you if that's work ;)

Comment: I have anothers questions, i don't understand really what is 'someUniqueid' it' s me who must define it ? The clientId is define automaticly ?

Comment: That's probably work but nothing appears on my client